# MySQL Order By multiple columns and with mixed results

Tags: php, mysql

Say i want to get my data and order by 3 columns

i currently have:

```
 ORDER BY e.HomePage DESC, e.FeaturedProfile DESC, e.DateModified DESC
```

this returns HomePage 1st, then FeaturedProfile 2nd these and the rest of the results are ordered by DateModified (some profiles are neither HomePage or FeaturedProfile so these get displayed below and sorted on DateModified only)

What i want it for the 1st results to be a mix of HomePage AND FeaturedProfile  ordered by DateModified and then any other results (that are neither HomePage or FeaturedProfile below )

Idealy i want to do this all within 1 query

EDIT:

Below is the full query (inc php code + i have replaced the bound variables for ease of reading):
the fields of HomePage and FeaturedProfile are boolean 
(this is for my main search function so sorry, it is quiet large)
Ideally i want all results returned but if HomePage and FeaturedProfile are = 1 i want these first and anything else below. i want HomePage and FeaturedProfile to be mixed together though but still above other results (i can do this with 2 queries, but am hoping to do it in a single query for neatness )

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT e.EscortID,
                e.EscortName,
                e.EscortEmail,
                e.EscortTelephone,
                e.EscortWebsite,
                e.InCallLocation,
                e.HairColour,
                g.GenderDescription,
                n.NationalityName,
                et.EthnicityName,
                ((date_format(now(),'%Y') - date_format(e.DateOfBirth,'%Y')) - (date_format(now(),'00-%m-%d') < date_format(e.DateOfBirth,'00-%m-%d'))) AS Age,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.EscortProfile,' ', 24) AS Description,
                p.PhotoAlt,
                p.PhotoURL,
                e.ShowReviews
                FROM tEscort e
                INNER JOIN tEscortArea ea ON e.EscortID = ea.tEscort_EscortID
                INNER JOIN tEthnicity et ON e.tEthnicity_EthnicityID = et.EthnicityID
                INNER JOIN tNationality n ON  e.tNationality_NationalityID = n.NationalityID
                INNER JOIN tGender g ON e.tGender_GenderID = g.GenderID AND g.Enabled=1
                LEFT JOIN tEscortAgency eag ON e.EscortID = eag.tEscort_EscortID
                LEFT JOIN tAgency a ON a.AgencyID = eag.tAgency_AgencyID 
                LEFT JOIN (tEscortPhoto ep INNER JOIN tPhoto p ON (ep.tPhoto_PhotoID = p.PhotoID AND p.Enabled=1)) 
                    ON e.EscortID = ep.tEscort_EscortID AND ep.ProfilePhoto = 1
                LEFT JOIN (tEscortEnjoyments ee INNER JOIN tEnjoyment en ON (ee.tEnjoyment_EnjoymentID = en.EnjoymentID AND en.Enabled=1))
                    ON e.EscortID = ee.tEscort_EscortID
                LEFT JOIN (tEscortServices es INNER JOIN tService s ON (s.ServiceID = es.tService_ServiceID AND s.Enabled=1)) 
                    ON e.EscortID = es.tEscort_EscortID
                WHERE e.Enabled=1
                AND e.Active=1
                AND e.AvctivePayments=1";

            if(!empty($areas)){$query .= " AND ea.tArea_AreaID IN($areas)";}
            if(!empty($enjoyments)){$query .= " AND ee.tEnjoyment_EnjoymentID IN($enjoyments)";}
            if(!empty($ethnicities)){$query .= " AND e.tEthnicity_EthnicityID IN($ethnicities)";}
            if(!empty($genders)){$query .= " AND e.tGender_GenderID IN($genders)";}
            if(!empty($nationalities)){$query .= " AND e.tNationality_NationalityID IN($nationalities)";}
            if(!empty($services)){$query .= " AND es.tService_ServiceID IN($services)";}
            if(!empty($hair)){$query .= " AND e.HairColour LIKE '%$hair%'";}
            if(!empty($braSize)){$query .= " AND e.tGender_GenderID != 1 AND e.BraSize IS NOT NULL AND e.BraSize REGEXP '$braSize'";}
            if(!empty($dressSize)){$query .= " AND e.tGender_GenderID != 1 AND e.DressSize IS NOT NULL AND e.DressSize >= $dressSize";}
            if(!empty($escortType))
            {
                switch ($escortType)
                {
                    case 'Agency' :
                        $query .= " AND eag.tAgency_AgencyID IS NOT NULL ";
                        break;
                    case 'Independent' :
                        $query .= " AND eag.tAgency_AgencyID IS NULL";
                        break;
                }
            }

            if(!empty($ageFrom) && !empty($ageTo)){
                $i = 0;             
                $query .= " AND (";     
                foreach($ageFrom  as $from)  {  
                    if($i > 0 ){
                        $query .= " OR ";   
                    }                   
                    $query .= " e.DateOfBirth BETWEEN '$ageTo[$i]' AND '$from' ";               
                    $i++;                   
                }
                $query .= " ) ";                
            }

            if(!empty($breasts)){
                $i = 0;             
                $query .= " AND (";     
                foreach($breasts  as $cupSize)   {  
                    if($i > 0 ){
                        $query .= " OR ";   
                    }                   
                    $query .= " e.BraSize IS NOT NULL AND e.BraSize REGEXP '$cupSize' ";                
                    $i++;                   
                }
                $query .= " ) ";                
            }

            if(!empty($incallAreas)){
                $i = 0;             
                $query .= " AND (";     
                foreach($incallAreas  as $incallArea)    {  
                    if($i > 0 ){
                        $query .= " OR ";   
                    }
                    $incallAreaSub = substr($incallArea, 0, 5);             
                    $query .= " e.InCallLocation IS NOT NULL AND (e.InCallLocation LIKE '%$incallArea%' OR e.InCallLocation LIKE '%$incallAreaSub%') ";             
                    $i++;                   
                }
                $query .= " ) ";                
            }

            if(!empty($freeText)){ $query .= " AND (e.EscortName LIKE '%$freeText%' OR a.AgencyName LIKE '%$freeText%')"; }

            switch ($orderBy)
            {
                case 'created' :
                    $query .= " ORDER BY e.DateCreated DESC";
                    break;
                case 'age' :
                    $query .= " ORDER BY e.DateOfBirth DESC";
                    break;
                case 'popularity' :
                    $query .= " ORDER BY e.ViewCount DESC";
                    break;
                default :
                    $query .= " ORDER BY e.DateModified DESC";
                    break;
            }

            $query .= " LIMIT $start, $pageSize";
```

Comment: I don't get it. Are `HomePage` and `FeaturedProfile` boolean fields?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes yes they are (i dont get it either :-) ). the main ordering is by DateModified i suppose, but to get the HomePage and FeaturedProfile be at the top i add them to the order, but i would like them to be mixed (sorry if i am not explaining myself well)

Comment: Well uhm no, I still don't get the question. It might help if you gave some sample input and output.

Comment: And an idea of what your db table looks like.

Comment: OK all. Thanks, i will have a rethink about how i am doing this (i can do it with 2 queries,but was trying to do it in 1 query). i will post back when i understand more too :-) + i will add the full query to the OP

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes. i have added the full query, so hope this helps. as you can see, i am far from an expert!!!

Comment: I think if I were you, I might have deleted the stuff that makes it obvious that the database is for an "escort" finder.

Comment: @ialarmedalien i did think this, but then it would not have made sense or would have been hard to rearrange. sorry if it offends anyone, but i would rather be honest.... PS it is perfectly legal in my country! + one of the many sites i work on

Comment: A sensible country! `:)` The main info that is needed is what `HomePage` and `FeaturedProfile` are (i.e. booleans). Too much other information can be distracting, and reams of code can put people off, unfortunately.

Comment: @ialarmedalien for once a sensible country, but not always :) HomePage and FeaturedProfile are both booleans. i can do this in 2 queries of first getting the home and featured profiles then in a second query getting the non home and featured and joining them in the php side of things, but this is messy and makes the limit and paging much more complicated....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227762/mysql-multiple-order-by-kind-of-nested